# Installing Linux kernel 2.6.25.14 on RHEL 5.4

Tags: linux, redhat, kernel

I have to install Linux kernel version 2.5.25.14 on a RHEL 5.4 server because of drive compatibility issues.  I follow [the RedHat "Building a Custom Kernel" instructions](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/linux/RHL-7.3-Manual/custom-guide/ch-custom-kernel.html) running the following:

```
$ make mrproper
$ make xconfig
$ make clean
$ make bzImage
$ make modules
$ make modules_install
$ make install
```

But I get a bunch of warnings like this:

```
WARNING: No module ehci-hcd found for kernel 2.6.25.24, continuing anyway
```

When I try to boot this kernel it is unable to mount the hard drive, and kernel panics on startup.  As far as I can tell I'm using a standard configuration (I just accept the defaults and save a `.config` file).  Is there something I'm missing?  Thanks.

Comment: Which issues? It might be work trying to backport the relevant modules if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say you just accept the defaults and save a `.config` file, you mean the defaults of the vanilla kernel from **kernel.org** ? In that case, I would suggest to copy the Red Hat customized config file from **/boot**, e.g. `/boot/config-2.6.18-194.el5PAE` to **/usr/src/linux** right after running `make mrproper`. Run `make oldconfig` afterwards and pay attention to the choices, read the help for the options and only if you are unsure, accept the default.

`make oldconfig` will create a new `.config` file for you, based on a `.config` from an older kernel, that is compatible with the tree that you are building. It drops options that don't exist in the new kernel, accepts choices for options that exist and are present in the old file, and asks for your choice for options that appeared after the old kernel.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of service ;)